# "Hiren's Boot CD 16.2" vs. "Hiren's Boot CD 15.2"

Tags: bootable-media, trojan, rescue, hiren

I was looking for the latest HBCD and then I found this one: **"Hiren's Boot CD *16.2*"** which seems to be the latest, however on their own website, they only have  vs. **"Hiren's Boot CD *15.2*"** not ***16.2*** which made me suspicious.

Here a few of the links I came across that mention Hiren Boot CD 16.2:

- http://thehillnews.net/news/Download-hiren-boot-cd-16.2-iso-free
- http://getpcsoft.wikisend.com/tips/Hiren_Bootcd_16.2_Windows_7.html

Does anyone know if this is fake, a virus, a trojan attempt by the KGB or something?

I don't see any question like this, only questions about the workings of hbcd 15.2 here, so there.

Comment: ALWAYS download software from it's developer site.

Answer (score 1):

I am a qualified and experienced enterprise IT support engineer and my answer is provided with the confidence of having a title and pay rate for over 20 years in this focus area, and usually get paid to detail KB updates.
This is free answer, so take it in the back pound @ramhound

I obtained an original CDROM from OP's point of inquiry and that CDROM has the absolute best answer as well as from the original source itself. Don't believe the downvotes from commenters who fail to list there sources of correct information and only say answers are wrong instead. If you know the answer, provide it, otherwise it's an exercise in turd nugget rammed in by @ramhound_him - wanna be IT dude providing bad mojo.
This is the original website. I have had this same Hirens Boot CD/DVD v15.2 for over 5 years and the following link was acquired directly off of this DVD. These types of tools are always **"Use at Your Own Risk"**.

[Hiren & Pankaj's Homepage](https://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk)

To answer your question; I would stick to the original website provided above as the best source, and not trust any other ports or revisions from anywhere else.

```
[hirens.info/pages/bootcd][1]
```

Comment: The domain in your answer and the official website specified by all other sources are registered by two entirely different people.  **I personally would not trust the domain specified in this answer.**

Comment: @Ramhound - I think there is a misunderstanding here. The "official" website is the one listed in this answer. In addition, there is a website https://www.hirensbootcd.org/  which is also "official". I suggest going to the "org" site & reading the "About" page where you can see the history. The "info" site has the original official version of  the boot CD, final version released indeed being 15.2 released years ago (and _not_ 16.2 - which you should avoid). The "org" site explains that development has been taken over by a community of fans and is now only 64-bit. Both sites are credible, IMHO.

Comment: @yoshm - I am still not going to trust it.

Comment: @yoshm , you compared my listing to your sources and stated I was wrong because it did not match your sources? Wouldn't a dispute countering my answer with such a statement saying your sources are the correct link. somehow, be sensible to include in your rebuttal? this is so easy for me...@yoshi_mario_kart_banana_peel